# How to get new password of Firebase Authentication Emailresetpassword

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an application which uses "Class MyUsers" and MyLogin() by my own, **not** by Users and login() of Firebase Authentication (FA).

I use the "Send email to reset password" service of FA, but it only changes the password of FA_Users.

How can I get this password to setValue() for my MyUsers? Or at least I can put a new password on this email?

P/S: it's too late to change all UserAccount in my project to FA_Users. There's a lot of work that I has to do.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can understand what the problem is.